# whitelist some inherrited variables (but not all) in gitlab multi-project pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm following the gitlab [docs for multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html). I'm running on gitlab.com (not enterprise/self-hosted).

I have successfully set up a multi-project pipeline. My question is - is there a way to pass some but not all variables between stages?

Here's a very simple build script for two projects:

Main project:

```yaml
variables:
  THIS_PROJECT_NAME: trigger-source
  SHARED_ARGUMENT: "hello world!"

stages:
  - build
  - downstream

build-code-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
    - echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"

run-trigger-job:
  stage: downstream
  inherit:
    variables: false
  variables:
    SHARED_ARGUMENT: $SHARED_ARGUMENT
  trigger: my-org/triggers_dest
```

Triggered project:

```yaml
variables:
    THIS_PROJECT_NAME: trigger-dest
    SHARED_ARGUMENT: "overwrite me"

stages:
  - test

triggered-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
    - echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"
  only:
    - pipelines
```

when I run this with `inherit: variables: false`, the output in the triggered project's builds just show the default variables (no variables are passed):

```bash
$ echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
trigger-dest
$ echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"
overwrite me
```

However, when I use `inherit: variables: true`, all variables are passed, except the value of SHARED_ARGUMENT is actually written as the literal `"$SHARED_ARGUMENT`, which then gets expanded to "overwrite me":

```bash
$ echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
trigger-source
$ echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"
overwrite me
```

This is the opposite of what I want! Essentially I want to whitelist variables to pass through, rather than blacklisting them as above. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer buried in the docs on the [`inherit: variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#inheritvariables) keyword. In addition to `true`/`false`, you can specify a list of variables to inherit.

Changing the source project's `.gitlab-ci.yml` to the following:

```yaml
variables:
  THIS_PROJECT_NAME: trigger-source
  SHARED_ARGUMENT: "hello world!"

stages:
  - build
  - downstream

build-code-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
    - echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"

run-trigger-job:
  stage: downstream
  inherit:
    variables:
    - SHARED_ARGUMENT
  trigger: my-org/triggers_dest
```

results in the desired output:

```bash
$ echo "${THIS_PROJECT_NAME}"
trigger-dest
$ echo "${SHARED_ARGUMENT}"
hello world!
```