# Multi Project pipeline Gitlab?

Tags: database, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, devops

This is the template of my database pipeline

```
#MySql
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
    - reset-data

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - docker build
    
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script: 
        - docker push

reset-data:
    stage: reset-data
    when: manual
    script: 
        - kubectl delete
        - kubectl apply
```

This is the template of my end-to-end test pipeline.

```
#E2E 
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
    - reset-data
    - test

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - docker build
    
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script: 
        - docker push

reset-data:
    stage: reset-data
    #Two things I want to achieve here
    #1) Call reset-data job from #MySql pipeline
    trigger:
        project: /compass/environment/mysql-data/
    #2) Change parameter when `manual` to `always`

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - npx cypress run
```

I am trying to call the specific job from one project to another GitLab project. Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this? I want to change the parameter of the parent job as well. Please look at the comments of reset-data job in `#E2E` pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Change `when: manual` to `only: triggers` then set whichever conditions you would like on the triggered job. You can pass variables into the downstream job  (and use them to define further rules) using the [`inherit: variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#inheritvariables) keyword.

See e.g. this question for another example: [whitelist some inherited variables (but not all) in a GitLab multi-project pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835943/whitelist-some-inherrited-variables-but-not-all-in-gitlab-multi-project-pipeli/72836031#72836031)

Comment: The thing is I don't want to reset the data every time MySql pipeline runs. I only want to reset it when the E2E pipeline runs. Basically, I want to change the yaml file of E2E project only.

Comment: if you change the condition to only run on `triggers`, only incoming triggered builds from other projects will be able to run that pipeline. If you limit all build stages on your MySQL build to only run with triggers, it will never run when the MySQL repo changes - only when the E2E repo changes. so this should do exactly what you're looking for. but you do need to configure your downstream yaml, not just your upstream yaml, to configure a trigger-only build stage.